# Using SSL with Tomcat and Spring

Tags: spring, tomcat, ssl, amazon-ec2

I would like to add encrypted connections to my Spring application running on a Tomcat server in a remote host (Amazon EC2 server). I was going to add a Let's Encrypt certificate to my Tomcat, but while searching on the web I read that encrypting my connections could considerably slow down my application. So I was wondering, what would be the best practice to encrypt my application? And does it really slow down so much my application that it would be noticeable? I would really like to implement the best solution, so I am very grateful in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (almost) universal practice is to put a proper high performance web server like nginx or Apache HTTPD in front of your application server acting as a reverse proxy and handling SSL. That way your application server stays on a private network and only a web server is exposed. It’s very easy and you can find many tutorials on how to set it up. Like this one: http://webapp.org.ua/sysadmin/setting-up-nginx-ssl-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you recommend to have a separate server for the web server or the same instance where my Tomcat is running would suffice? Also, between nginx and Apache, would you recommend one above the other one?

Comment: Yes usually that's what you want. In EC2 you want to configure 2 subnets (one public and one private). Your nginx will live in a public and private subnet (2 IP addresses) and you application server only in the private subnet. Between nginx and httpd I think there is no difference. Just choose what you feel you'll be more comfortable with.

Comment: @Strelok In EC2, you can simply use ELB as your web server(s) without an additional layer in between.